# w3p3.exe not found when "Attach to process"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Sometimes I attempt to Debug with VS2010 but no aspnet worker process is found when I try to attach to w3p3.exe. If I restart VS2010 it's back again.

Any solution to this without restarting VS?
thank you !!

Comment: Have you already tried to access a page on the site?  The worker process is likely set to shut down after a period of inactivity and you will need to makea request to start it up again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worker process may have exited - you will need to browse to the site to restart the worker process.

At this point you will be able to attach to it again.

Comment: Yes, I'll do it and it worked but how can I handle when the w3p3 exites from memory?

Comment: @senyortoni - You browse to the site again. With Visual Studio, when not debugging, simply `F5` to relaunch.